# Fix user input not continuing until the entered user input loops to match its index in the array

Tags: c#

The problem I have is that when I enter an element from the array, the user input resets to the start of the loop, for example when i user input the third element from the array, the user input question two more times to continue to the next user input question, how can I fix this? everybody know what I can adjust here.
[worked loop image with 1st element entered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKstu.png)
[looping error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPNtB.png)

```
        while (true)
        {
            String[] bgtype = { "cheeseburger","tlc", "bbq" };
            int[] bgtypeprice = { 15, 25, 10 };
            int max = bgtype.Length;
            String[] product = new string[max];
            String[] type = new string[max];
            int[] qty = new int[max];
            int[] disc = new int[max];

            Console.WriteLine("");

            for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("What PRODUCT would you like to buy ?: "); ;
                product[i] = Console.ReadLine();
                if (product[i].Equals("burger", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    {
                        Console.Write("What TYPE of product would you like to buy?: ");
                        type[i] = Console.ReadLine();
                        if (bgtype[i].Contains(type[i]))
                        {
                            Console.Write("Enter your discount % (5% for adults & 7% for minors): ");
                            disc[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                            Console.Write("How many will you buy? ");
                            qty[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                            float total = bgtypeprice[i]; total *= qty[i];
                            Console.WriteLine("Total cost of " + type[i] + " " + product[i] + " is: " + qty[i] + " pieces x P" + bgtypeprice[i] + "= P" + total);
                            float totaldisc = 0; totaldisc = (total * disc[i]) / 100;
                            Console.WriteLine("Total amount of discount: P " + totaldisc);
                            float totalamt = 0; totalamt = total - totaldisc;
                            Console.WriteLine("Total cost of order: P " + totalamt);
                            Console.WriteLine("-------------------ORDER CONFIRMATION-------------------");
                            }}}}}
```

Comment: So, about [those methods I talked about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65463969/c-sharp-how-to-add-records/65466002#65466002)..

Answer (score 0):

`if (bgtype[i].Contains(type[i]))` should be changed to `if (bgtype.Contains(type[i]))`
Array.Contains, verifies if an item is contained within an **Array**, not an **Array value**. By asking if `bgtype[i]` contains `type[i]`, you are asking if `cheesburger` contains `tlc`, which it doesn't, hence why it starts from the beginning. By verifying if `bgtype` contains `type[i]`, you are asking if `["cheesburger", "tlc", "bbq"]` contains `tlc`, which it does. I hope this was clear enough.